How to modify these two functions to meet certain criteria? Problem with instantaneous rate of change
Taking an online course. I've been given a question which they haven't remotely prepared me to solve. It is the following:
Rod says that he is thinking of two functions that have the following characteristics:
a. One is rational, and has a y-intercept at -2
b. One is trigonometric, and does not include the cosine function
c. One contains the digit “3” and the other does not.
d. Both have an instantaneous rate of change of 1.23 (rounded to two decimal
places) at  = 2
e. The two functions intersect at  = 2
Provide one example of a pair of functions that meet Rod’s criteria.
There is actually a previous answer to this on Reddit (here: https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/18q2tz3/functions_question/), which I checked, and it works. But I want to understand how he reached that answer. I lose the plot completely at this point:
1.23 = g'(2) = p sec^2 (2 - 2) = p
Everything that follows is also confusing. We've been given the standard equation to solve instantaneous rates of change:
instantaneous rate of change = [ f(x+0.001)-f(x) ] / 0.001
And I understand how that works, but not how to work backwards and derive a formula when given the slope (=1.23) and a point (x=2), etc.
If there is a different method for solving this problem, also quite happy to hear about that.

'One contains the digit "$3$" and the other does not' and 'One is trigonometric, and does not include the cosine function' - are surefire indications that this is a trash problem from someone who is phoning it in rather than making a serious effort to educate. "Rational" is a well-defined property of functions. "Trigonometric" is not so well-defined, but at least one has some idea as to what it means (If one is not careful in laying out a definition, every function could be considered "trigonometric").

But "contains the digit 3" and "does not include the cosine function" are not definable properties of functions. A mere recasting of your definition can easily remove any $3$ or $\cos$ to be found in it, without changing the function at all (i.e., it is still defined on the same set of inputs, and provides the same output for each of those inputs).

Your formula for calculating the instantaneous rate of change is just an approximation to it rather than the actual value. To calculate the actual instantaneous rate of change, you need calculus. This is where $g'$ comes in. That notation refers to the derivative of $g$, which gives the actual instantaneous rate of change of $g$ at each point in its domain.
In the solution the author arbitrarily assumes that $f$ has the form $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{v(x)}\\g(x) = p\tan(x-2)$$
where $v(x)$ is some polynomial with $v(0) = 1, v(2) \ne 0$ and $p$ is some as-yet undetermined constant. This arbitrary assumption was made because there are uncountably many functions that meet these conditions (ignoring the two I mentioned in the comments that actually have no meaning). So they are just starting with choices that allow them to complete the task easily. Note that both functions are chosen to have value $0$ at $x = 2$, thus ensuring they intersect there, and the conditions on $v$ ensure that $f$ has the right $y$-intersept and is defined at $x = 2$.
So the remaining real conditions to be met are that both have instantaneous rate of change $1.23$ at $x = 2$.
For that, rather than your approximation, they pull out the derivative. I am not going to explain derivatives. Calculus is big subject, and this is not a forum to adequately explain it. There are many resources on-line that you can use to figure how to take the derivatives of these functions. I will just give you the results:
$$g'(x) = p\sec^2(x-p)$$
and $$f'(x) = \frac{v(x) - (x-2)v'(x)}{[v(x)]^2}$$
where $v'$ is the derivative of $v$. So the two conditions we need are $f'(2) = 1.23$ and $g'(2) = 1.23$. So he evaluates $g'$ at $x = 2$ to get $g'(2) = p$, and thus concludes that $p = 1.23$. Similarly, $f'(2) = \frac 1{v(2)} = 1.23$ gives another requirement on $v$: $$v(0) = 1\\v(2) = \frac 1{1.23}$$ which then also satisfies the weaker previous condition of $v(2) \ne 0$. Note that since $x-2 = 0$ when $x = 2$, the derivative $v'$ at $2$ was unneeded.
Now they decide to assume $v$ is a degree 2 polynomial. Since there are two conditions on $v$ to be met, there need to be two parameters in $v$ that can be adjusted to meet those conditions. A degree 1 polynomial $v(x) = ax + b$ would have been sufficient. I can only guess they made it degree 2 to introduce a third parameter that could be adjusted to meet the spurious requirement to not contain the digit "$3$". So they set $v(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, then set $c = 1$ so that $v(0) = 1$. Then choosing $a = -10$ (again, arbitrary, other than avoiding that frightful $3$), they use $v(2) = \frac 1{1.23}$ to arrive at $b = 19.9065$ (where they have rounded off the exact value). No $3$s in evidence, so we are done.

Now if they has chosen $a = 0$ instead, the equation $v(2) = \frac 1{1.23}$ becomes $$2b + 1 = \frac 1{1.23}\\b = -0.093496$$ (again, rounded). And $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{1 - 0.093496x}\\g(x) = 1.23 \tan (x-2)$$
Oh No! A $3$ in both functions! But this is easily handled in many ways:
$$g(x) = 1.229\tan (x-2)\\g(x) = 1.1214_6\tan (x-2)\\g(x) = (1.4-0.17)\tan(x-2)\\f(x) = \frac{2x - 4}{2 - 0.\overline{18699}x}$$ (The "6" subscript in the 2nd solution indicates the number is expressed in base 6, not the normal base 10.)
